# How do i trigger function at the end of div scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery infinity pagination .i have div in which products are dynamically call let say

```
<div id="product_list">
<?php include ('products.php'); ?>
</div>
```

now how do i trigger `loadMoreData()` function when user reach on last product i try this but work at the end of page .

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
     var last_id = $(".post-id:last").attr("id");
        alert(last_id);
        loadMoreData(last_id);
      }
});
 function loadMoreData(last_id){
  $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id,
            type: "get",
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('.ajax-load').show();
            }
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            $("#post-data").html(data);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
              alert('server not responding...');
        });
}
```

Comment: “i try this but work at the end of page” – I don't understand what you mean by that. The `loadMoreData` function is called, I've tried that in a fiddle. Could you please describe the expected behavior more specifically, and what your code currently does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sample code and then modify the scroll function per your needs,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="product_list">
 <div style="background-color: green; height: 400px;"></div>
 <div style="background-color: blue; height: 400px;"></div>
 <div style="background-color: green; height: 400px;"></div>
 <div style="background-color: blue; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: green; height: 100px;"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $("#product_list").height()) {

        alert("hi");
}
});
</script>
```

This code calculates the window height and compares it with the `div (product_list)` height. If scrolled to the end of the div, then an `alert` is popped up.